# Can a session be shared between browsers from the same computer in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session

I have a scenario where multiple users are using my **ruby-on-rails ( rails version 3+ )** app to access xml feeds.

These feeds need to different for each user session, but if a user was to access the feed from his browser or from a desktop application that pulls those feeds, the session needs to remain the same.

I cannot designate sessions based on IP addresses, because sometimes multiple users will have the same IP.

Is there a way to to share the sessions that come from the same computer in rails?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about doing something like:

1. User fetches feed from browser => gets session id `"1234"`
2. User opens desktop app
3. Desktop app requests user to "authorize app" => generate unique token in app `"abcd"`
4. Desktop app opens "authorize app url" in browser => `https://x.y/authorize?token=abcd
5. Rails app then gets 1. current session & 2. the token

Comment: You *might* also get some ideas from devise's [remember_across_browsers](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise.rb#L106) feature. Check out how that is implemented.

Answer (score 0):

I can imagine only IP solution or you can try to find out MAC address and store it for each user (encrypted)