# How to control if a user logins twice in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, authentication, devise

Right now Iam using **devise** for an application and I don't want a user to login twice, if it logins for the second time his previous session would be killed. this way the user can't login with two browsers, for example he logins first with firefox and then logins with google chrome the firefox session expires.

Comment: Maybe can be good if you accept some answer before

Comment: thanks shingara for the warning :)

Answer (score 0):

Something similar here: [Can a session be shared between browsers from the same computer in rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5511031/can-a-session-be-shared-between-browsers-from-the-same-computer-in-rails)

Comment: Not the same scenario. I don't want the user to login twice to the app and if it does one of the sessions is killed